# Angulajs: How to apply filter using select form after clicking save button?

Tags: angularjs

In table I'm displaying name, designation and company of employees. I want to use select form to select the name of company. When I select company name and then click save button as result I only want to display names, designations and company of employees that for example work for Google.
Also I want to have displayed number of how many employee is it.

But kinnda got stucked my save button is not working, and also don't have number of employe.

file.html

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:10%">#</th>
                <th style="width:20%">Name</th>
                <th style="width:40%">Designation</th>
                <th style="width:30%">Company</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in clients">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.designation}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.company.name}}</td>
            </tr>
            </table>

     </div>  
 <div>
    <ul>
       <li>
       <h2>Select Company:</h2>

            <select ng-model="selectedCompany">
            <option ng-repeat="c in companyList" value="{{c.name}}">{{c.name}}</option>
            </select>

            <h3>You selected: {{selectedCompany}}</h3>


        </li>
    </ul>
        <button ng-click="$ctrl.updateSearch()">Filter</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

file.js

```
var controllers = angular.module('MyApp.controllers', [])
        controllers.controller('MyController', function  ($scope) {


              $scope.clients = [{
                    name: 'Brett',
                    designation: 'Software Engineer',
                    company: {
                        name: 'Apple'
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'Steven',
                    designation: 'Database Administrator',
                    company: {
                        name: 'Google'
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'Jim',
                    designation: 'Designer',
                    company: {
                        name: 'Facebook'
                }
                }, {
                    name: 'Michael',
                    designation: 'Front-End Developer',
                    company: {
                        name: 'Apple'
                }
                }, {
                    name: 'Josh',
                    designation: 'Network Engineer',
                    company: {
                        name: 'Google'
                }
                }, {
                    name: 'Ellie',
                    designation: 'Internet Marketing Engineer',
                    company: {
                        name: 'Apple'
                }
                }];

              $scope.companyList = [{
                         name: 'Apple',
                        slug: 'Apple'
                         }, {
                        name: 'Google',
                        slug: 'Google'
                        }, {
                        name: 'Microsoft',
                        slug: 'Microsoft'
                        }, {
                         name: 'Facebook',
                        slug: 'Facebook'
                        },

                    ];
                     $scope.updateSearch = function() {
                    console.log($scope.selectedCompany);

    }

        });
```

Comment: Is that your trying to get input values after clicking on save button ?

Comment: You want to get the selected values?

Comment: I have group of displayed shirts. So what I'm trying to accomplish is when I for example select color:blue size:m and brand: nike and than click save button, I get lists of all available shirts in color:blue size:m and brand: nike.

Answer (score 1):

There are few changes needs to be done on your view, Change your model variables to be different from the array names, such as colorn,sizen and brandn.

```
<div>
  <label>Color:</label>
  <select  ng-model="colorn" ng-options="option.name for option in colorStatus track by option.slug"></select>
</div>
 <div>
  <label>Size</label>
  <select ng-model="sizen" ng-options="option.name for option in size track by option.slug"></select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Brand</label>
  <select ng-model="brandn" ng-options="option.name for option in $ctrl.brand track by option.slug"></select>
</div>
  <button ng-click="updateSearch()">Save</button>
```

Also you can get the values using your $scope variable,

**Controller**

```
$scope.updateSearch = function(){
console.log($scope.colorn);
console.log($scope.sizen);
console.log($scope.sizen);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/qS77bMszyIYu21sddQjy?p=preview)**

Comment: Hy I edited my question can you look at it now? Have applied you updateSearch function solution but it's not working.